# Meteorjs + Angular 2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor, typescript, angular

I am attempting the Meteor/Angular2 tutorial [here](https://github.com/ShMcK/Meteor-Angular2)

If I make a change to a component the changes are not updated in the browser (Google Chrome); even if I do the following things...

1. Save changes and hard refresh browser.
2. Stop server and restart.

I have to clear the browser cache to get rid of the old data and load the new.

I'm pretty sure this should not be the case, as it creates a major problem for a developer.

This tutorial is using Angular2, Meteorjs, as well as a typescript compiler.

This is not an Angular issue.

My question is... Is the problem with meteorjs not triggering a hard refresh? Or could it perhaps be an issue with the typescript compiler?

Also, how could I fix this?

I'm running

Typescript Compiler: netanelgilad:angular2-typescript

Meteorjs: 1.2.2

Google Chrome: Version 47.0.2525.0 canary (64-bit)

**UPDATE:**

I tried a normal .js file and everything works as expected. This means its the Typescript Compiler: netanelgilad:angular2-typescript.

I'll check out the package and see what I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You are using

> http-server

then this may be the issue of http-server as it always store the data in cache.

In my case i was using http-server and this problem occured.

You can fix it by selecting the disable cache option in developer tools(chrome).

Comment: This worked. Is the http-server the generic server that Meteor runs?

Comment: Also, why do the .js and .html files load regardless of cache, but the .ts do no?

Comment: @SoEzPz According to me, Browser has only concerned with the html and js files not with the ts files.

Comment: http-server is not the generic server for meteor.you can also run meteor using apache server.[link](http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/45184656062/running-your-meteorjs-application-on-your-own)

Comment: See this link for reference :: [link](http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/45184656062/running-your-meteorjs-application-on-your-own)